# Error creating Oracle text index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to create a text index and running into issues.

```
EXEC ctx_ddl.create_preference('DRG_INDX_DST','multi_column_datastore');
EXEC ctx_ddl.set_attribute('DRG_INDX_DST', 'columns', 'DRG, DESCRIPTION');
EXEC ctx_ddl.create_section_group('DRG_INDX_SG', 'auto_section_group');

DROP INDEX DRG_SEARCH_IDX FORCE;
CREATE INDEX DRG_SEARCH_IDX ON MYTABLE_IND( DRG )
       INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context
       PARAMETERS( 'datastore DRG_INDX_DST section group DRG_INDX_SG');
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10700: preference does not exist: CTXSYS.NONE_DATATYPE
```

What is `CTXSYS.NONE_DATATYPE`?

Comment: What's the data type of DRG?

Comment: Both DRG and DESCRIPTION are VARCHAR2.

Comment: Can you test without the PARAMETERS clause? Maybe the error is misleading.

Comment: Well, DBA reinstalled text index option, all default preferences are created this time. But I'm getting disconnected from oracle every time I'm trying to create any index: ORA-03113 end-of-file on communication chanel.     DROP INDEX drg_index FORCE;   CREATE INDEX drg_index ON MYTABLE_IND( DRG ) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context;